# asp.net datagrid view row selection into textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datagrid

i need help getting the row selection into the text box's when the user clicks the edit button in the grid view, i have the event and will show you the code i have tried.
I am running on visual studio 2013 and sql server 2012.

```
txtname.Text = gridview.Rows[gridview.SelectedIndex].Cells[1].Text;

txtname.Text = gridview.Rows[gridview.SelectedRow].Cells[1].Text;
```

[screens] https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcLiY.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i used a combination of both your answers and came up with this one which works fine:

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(gridview.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex].Value);
    txtid.Text = id.ToString();
    txtname.Text = gridview.Rows[id].Cells[3].Text;
    txtadd.Text = gridview.Rows[id].Cells[4].Text;
    txtcountry.Text = gridview.Rows[id].Cells[5].Text;
    txtcity.Text = gridview.Rows[id].Cells[6].Text;
    txtpin.Text = gridview.Rows[id].Cells[7].Text;
```

Let me know what you think and if this is bad coding let me know aswell.

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `gridview.SelectedIndex` you should have an event arg and grab it's index. From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowediting(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2):

```
protected void TaskGridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
  {
    //Set the edit index.
    TaskGridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    //Bind data to the GridView control.
    BindData();
  }
```

So yours would be:

```
protected void gridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
   txtname.Text = gridview.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[1].Text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly create a Gridview using code below

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GV" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  OnRowEditing="GV_RowEditing" DataKeyNames="id">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Username">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Column1")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Password">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Column2")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="edit" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" >Edit</asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

then generate the row editing event of gridview and in that write this code

```
 string id = GV.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex].Value.ToString();
    string select = "select * from tblLogin where id ='"+Convert.ToInt16(id)+"'";
    ds = gs.select(select);
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
       lblName.Text= ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Column1"].ToString();
        lblPass.Text=ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Column2"].ToString();
    }
```

hope this will help